# File chooser problem

Tags: 18.04

When I'm using drawio and I want to open an existed diagram, instead of popup immediately, it's popup a notification that "drawio is ready" when the others is not like that.

Please tell me how to fix this! Thanks in advanced

Comment: As it looks like a glitch, you should probably report it to the team. Also you may tell us how do you try to open. Is it from file explorer using "open with"?

Comment: @JijoJoseph it's from File --> Open. I don't know why thís doesn't happen to other application.

Comment: It's a bug you may report it as mentioned by @Matigo

Answer (score 1):

As Drawio is [an open source application](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop), there are two options; one hard and one easy.

Hard ⇢ [Download the code](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/), make the changes, and maybe share them back
Easy ⇢ [Submit a feature request](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/issues), as there are probably other people who also have the same request

Hope this helps

Comment: OMG :)) I've never thinked of it before but I think you right